# Interraction Spinner with EditText

Tags: java, android

I am working with this [library](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject). I have country list with countries phone code in Spinner. When I choose a country I need to display country code in EditText field. This is my code:

```
CountryCodePicker ccp;
String countryCode;
EditText phoneNumberEditText;

ccp = (CountryCodePicker) findViewById(R.id.country_cod_picker);
final CountryCodePicker ccp = new CountryCodePicker(this);
phoneNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number_edit_text);
countryCode = ccp.getSelectedCountryCode();
ccp.setOnCountryChangeListener(new CountryCodePicker.OnCountryChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCountrySelected() {
        phoneNumberEditText.setText(countryCode);
    }
});
```

My app doesn't crash, but contry code doesn't display. Help me please! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
 Remove this line

```
final CountryCodePicker ccp = new CountryCodePicker(this);
```

2.
Modify your code as follows

```
ccp.setOnCountryChangeListener(new CountryCodePicker.OnCountryChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCountrySelected() {
      countryCode = ccp.getSelectedCountryCode();
      phoneNumberEditText.setText(countryCode);
 }
});
```

You need to call `ccp.getSelectedCountryCode()`in the callback, otherwise your `countryCode` variable will still have the old value assigned.

Comment: I did it - now my app crashes. I have java.lang.NullPointerException and java.lang.RuntimeException

Answer (score 0):

One problem: the line "final CountryCodePicker ccp = new CountryCodePicker(this);" hides the ccp variable that you set in the previous line. I don't understand the need to create a new CountryCodePicker. The findViewById should return a valid CountryCodePicker (assuming you added a CountryCodePicker to your layout). I would remove the line "final CountryCodePicker ccp = new CountryCodePicker(this);"

If findViewById() returns null, that says that there is no "country_cod_picker" in your layout. I'm guessing country_cod_picker is a typo, that the line should read "R.id.country_code_picker" instead (missing letter e).